# How to convert ogg to aac music format?

Tags: command-line, conversion, ogg-vorbis, aac

I want to convert a ogg file to aac. But I need to transfer all the data of the ogg file (i.e. album, year, cover,...) to the aac file using a shell comand.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Answer (score 4):

```
ffmpeg -i input.ogg -strict experimental -acodec aac output.aac
```

you can find ffmpeg in the official repository.

Comment: Mmm sorry, but the sound quality isn't good and the tags of the original file didn't copy.

Comment: @BrallanAguilar Unfortunately the sound quality will generally not be good when [converting from one lossy format to another](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossy#Transcoding_and_editing). You should [avoid doing so when possible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcoding#Drawbacks).

Answer (score 3):

Transcoding from one lossy format to another is not ideal. However, if you insist on doing so, this is the best way: install avconv and ubuntu-restricted-extras with

```
sudo apt-get install avconv ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

then get neroAacEnc:

```
wget http://ftp6.nero.com/tools/NeroAACCodec-1.5.1.zip
sudo unzip NeroAACCodec-1.5.1.zip -d /usr/bin linux/*
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/neroAacDec /usr/bin/neroAacEnc /usr/bin/neroAacTag
```

NeroAacEnc is superior to avconv's internal AAC encoder, and also much better than libfaac, it consistently scores highly on listening tests; and Nero have released it free for non-commercial use.

To create an M4A (MP4) file, use

```
avconv -i input.ogg -f wav - | neroAacEnc -if - -ignorelength -q 0.55 -of output.m4a
```

The -q flag can use any value between 0 and 1, with 1 being highest-quality; according to [this](http://wiki.hydrogenaudio.org/index.php?title=NeroAAC#Quality.2Fbitrate_control), 0.55 averages to a bit rate of 192 kb/s; a lower -q of around 0.4 would probably actually be perfectly suitable for most music listening. Experiment to find out what works best for you.

Unfortunately, this won't keep the metadata; but you can transfer the metadata from input.ogg to output.m4a with a second command:

```
avconv -i output.m4a -i input.ogg -map 0 -map_metadata 1 -c copy output.m4a
```

Comment: I found the last command did not copy the metadata correctly, but that this did: `avconv -i output.m4a -i input.ogg -map 0 -c copy -map_metadata 1:s:a final_output.m4a`

Answer (score 0):

Use [**Soundconverter**](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/soundconverter) [image: Install soundconverter]

And change `type of result` to AAC under `Edit` -> `Preferences`

Comment: I tried it. But the problem is metadata (tag information like cover, artist,...) isn't copied.

Comment: This uses FAAC which -to my ear- results in horrible sounding music.

Answer (score 0):

Footbar 2000 can work well to convert music files

Comment: Mmm sorry, where I can obtain it?

Comment: It's not a native Linux application.

Comment: @AAC Even better, you could expand this answer to explain how to obtain foobar2000, how to get it working in Ubuntu with Wine (since it's a Windows program), and specifically how to use it to convert files (screenshots would be a plus, too).